# Show that no GCD exists for $4$ and $2 \cdot (1 + \sqrt{-3})$ in $\{ x + y \sqrt{-3} | x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I need to show that there is no greatest common divisor for $4$ and $2 \cdot(1 + \sqrt{-3})$ in the ring $R := \{ x + y \cdot\sqrt{-3} \,\,|\,\, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I found that both $2$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-3})$ divide $4$ as well as $2 \cdot(1 + \sqrt{-3})$. Therefore if $x$ was a greatest common divisor of the two, it has to be divisible by both $2$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-3})$.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107304/showing-that-gcd-does-not-exist-for-31-sqrt-5-and-31-sqrt-5-in-m). You can use information about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473906/questions-about-mathbbz-sqrt-3?rq=1).

Comment: Note, a GCD of $2\alpha$ and $2\beta$ implies a GCD of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the common divisor of $4$ and $2(1+\sqrt{-3})$ be $x+y\sqrt{-3}$. Then we have
\begin{align}
(x+y\sqrt{-3})(a+b\sqrt{-3})&=4,\\
(x+y\sqrt{-3})(c+d\sqrt{-3})&=2(1+\sqrt{-3}),
\end{align}
where $x,y,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying $x-y\sqrt{-3}$ on both sides of the equations, one obtains
\begin{align}
a&=\frac{4x}{x^2+3y^2},\quad
b=-\frac{4y}{x^2+3y^2},\\
c&=\frac{2(x+3y)}{x^2+3y^2},\quad
d=\frac{2(x-y)}{x^2+3y^2}.
\end{align}
The denominators have higher degrees than the numerators, so the number of integer pairs of $(x,y)$ that makes $|a|\geq1$ or $|b|\geq 1$ or $|c|\geq 1$ or $|d|\geq 1$ is finite. One can therefore enumerate all such cases. After ruling out them all, the only possibility left is $a=b=c=d=0$, which cannot hold either (not allowed to have $x=y=0$ as they appear in the denominators), thus completing the proof.

Comment: How can you divide (by $x^2$, etc) in the first place? Rings don't necessarily provide multiplicative inverses.

Comment: I have $(x^2+3y^2)(a+b\sqrt{-3})=4(x-y\sqrt{-3})$. By comparing the coefficients of 1 and $\sqrt{-3}$, the solutions are given by $a=4x/(x^2+3y^2)$ and $b=-4y/(x^2+3y^2)$ if $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ exist.

Comment: In a ring no such thing as $(x^2 + 3y^2)^{-1}$ exists. How can this be part of a solution?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring. If $(x^2+3y^2)a=4x$, we know in general $(x^2+3y^2)$ is not invertible because $1/(x^2+3y^2)\notin\mathbb{Z}$. But if $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ exists, it must equal $a=4x/(x^2+3y^2)$. When abstract algebraic objects confuse us, think of our familiar friends $\mathbb{Z}$ (a ring), $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ (fields).

Comment: Hi! I see it is quite some time since this question was posted, but I was wondering if @ZhuoranHe is still active or if anyone else knows the answer and perhaps want to help... I am simply wondering why we choose to multiplying the equations by $x - y \sqrt{-3}$ on each side?