# Show that $a$ and $b$ have no greatest common divisor in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt-5]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $a=3\cdot 7 \cdot(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ and $b=(1+2\sqrt{-5})\cdot 7\cdot(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ have no greatest common divisor.

Since $N(a)=3^3\cdot 7^3$ and $N(b)=3^2\cdot 7^4$ so it is clear that any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must have norm dividing $3^2\cdot 7^3$. Now we will get many possibilities. Am I on right track or there is some other smart way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use \cdot instead of "." for denoting multiplication.

Comment: Do you mean $b = (1-2\sqrt{-5})\cdot 7\cdot(1+2\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: Do you mean "any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must have norm *dividing* $3^2\cdot7^3$"?

Comment: @GregMartin. Yes!

Comment: I'd start by checking why the obvious common factor $7\cdot(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ fails to be a gcd.

Comment: I Hope [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450749/show-that-no-gcd-exists-for-4-and-2-cdot-1-sqrt-3-in-x-y-sqrt?rq=1) will be helpful. In your approach, starting looks fine, you have to take a step further to prove there is no gcd.

Comment: Consider $3\cdot7=\left(1-2\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$.

Comment: @robjohn: It just helps to see that only possible candidate for GCD is $1+2 \sqrt-5$?

Comment: $7\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$ is a common divisor, so $1+2\sqrt{-5}$ could not be the GCD. Using $3\cdot7=\left(1-2\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$, we get that $\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2$ is also a common divisor.

Comment: @robjohn: From this, how does it follow  that $a$ and $b$ have no GCD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\gcd\left(3\cdot7\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right),7\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2\right)=7\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)\gcd\left(3,\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)\right)
$$
Since $N(3)=9$ and $N\!\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)=21$, we must have
$$
\left.N\!\left(\gcd\left(3,\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)\right)\right)\,\middle|\ 3\right.
$$
But the only element whose norm divides $3$ is $1$.

This would say that the $\gcd$ is $7\!\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$

---

Because $3\cdot7=\left(1-2\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)$, the $\gcd$ is also
$$
\gcd\left(\left(1-2\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2,7\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2\right)=\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2\gcd\left(1-2\sqrt{-5},7\right)
$$
Since $N\!\left(1-2\sqrt{-5}\right)=21$ and $N(7)=49$, we must have
$$
\left.N\!\left(\gcd\left(1-2\sqrt{-5},7\right)\right)\,\middle|\ 7\right.
$$
But the only element whose norm divides $7$ is $1$.

This would say that the $\gcd$ is $\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2$

---

$N\!\left(7\!\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)\right)=1029$ and $N\!\left(\left(1+2\sqrt{-5}\right)^2\right)=441$, so these numbers are not associates (the only units here are $\pm1$, so this can be seen simply).

This contradiction says that a $\gcd$ does not exist.